# Can you modify this BNF grammar to always contain an odd number of dogs?

Tags: parsing, syntax, bnf

Can you modify this BNF grammar to always contain an odd number of dogs?

```
<pets> ::= <pets> <pet> | <pet>
<pet>  ::= dog | cat
```

Examples of 'pets':

```
    dog cat
    cat dog
    dog dog dog
    dog dog cat cat dog
    dog cat dog dog
```

Not examples of 'pets':

```
cat
dog cat dog
cat cat
```

Comment: This is something that would be better suited to the post-parse analysis, or to a semantic predicate.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post what you have thought of, and we can give some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to conceptually have a state machine. You are in one of two states: you have seen an odd number of dogs, or you have seen an even number of dogs.

Try:

```
// 0 or more cats
<cats> ::= cat <cats> | ""
// 1 dog possibly surrounded by cats
<one_dog> ::= <cats> dog <cats>

<even_dogs> ::= <one_dog> <one_dog> <even_dogs> | <cats>
<odd_dogs> ::= <even_dogs> <one_dog>
```

It could use some cleaning up, but it should work. The key thing to note that < cats > and  will match against nothing. The only thing that production that must have a token is < one_dog >.